# Redraw the pie chart in oval shape highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

is it possible to redraw the piechart (highcharts.com), to a oval shape, as shown in the figure [image]

and also the shadow kind of things at the right side.

i tried this code

```
// Radialize the colors
            Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
                return {
                    radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, color],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                    ]
                };
            });
```

But not much change displayed, here is the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jhAD8/

please have a look,

Answer (score 1):

3D charts are not supported, included change perpective as you posted above. But You can vote for it http://highcharts.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0):

Update: 3D charts are supported. To get the chart you are looking for you could set a beta angle rotation in a 3D pie chart. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/41004emr/

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 0,
                beta: 45
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                depth: 35,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox', 45.0],
                ['IE', 26.8],
                ['Chrome',12.8],
                ['Safari', 8.5],
                ['Opera', 6.2],
                ['Others', 0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```